# Use htaccess with CDN

Tags: .htaccess, cdn

My existing developed site image url is  `http://domain.com/assets/`

at present we want to use CDN with pull

my CDN image url is `http://cdn.cdndomain.com/`

how to use cdn for my existing site. We dont want to change existing html image paths. how to rewrite with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this to your domain.com document root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ http://cdn.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Although this does redirect all asset requests to the CDN domain, the main server **still gets called for each asset**. It then returns a "301 Mover Permanently" HTTP code. I'm wondering if this is not bad for server performance. Can anyone elaborate on this?

EDIT: someone agrees with my point of view: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13318619/269622

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider is that CDN providers will allow you to do the rewrites at the CDN edge network which will keep all the overhead of the rewrites away from your Origin servers.