# CDN Related : Rewrite Image URLs automatically from .htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, url-rewriting, cdn

Recently I bought a CDN and set it up. In my site, the images are stored in a folder named 'images' and the Image urls are obviously linked in this manner. (*Ex : images/some_image.png*)

Since I want to use the CDN right way, I need to rewrite the urls without having to manually change each and every image path.

I tried an .htaccess code which was suggested for a similar problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://cdn.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But that didn't seem to work properly as all the images were linked improperly.

So I would like to know the changes in this code. Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Do your Urls redirect to `http://cdn.mydomain.com/some_image.png` and where do you want them to redirect to i.e. what do you mean they are not linked properly?

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^(images/.*)$ http://cdn.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`. But what is the use of a CDN if every image requires 2 http request to download? One that returns a 301, and one for the actual resource. You really need to change the html instead, to get speed improvements, and less traffic/load on your regular webserver.

Comment: @Gerben Thank you. That solved the problem. I get your point on the double http requests. will change the html instead directly.

Comment: @UlrichPalha They weren't appearing properly. Images were getting linked in an abnormal way. Like 1 is linked with 2 and 2 with 4. Anyways as Gerben suggested, will change it manually.

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^images\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/cdn\.yourdomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

However, please note that this is just a temporary solution!
In order to get the max out of your CDN, you need manually point images to your CDN in order to save one HTTP for every image.