# What is the simplest way to change the domain for all images?

Tags: html

This is the domain of my website

```
www.mydomain.com
```

And now I added new server, and moved all image to this server

```
cdn.mydomain.com
```

In my website, there are two cases.

case 1:

```
<head>
<base href="//www.mydomain.com">
</head>

<body>
<img src="img/internalImage.jpg">
<a href="internalLink.html">internal link</a>
</body>
```

case 2:

```
<head>
<base href="//www.mydomain.com">
</head>

<body>
<!--
Value of $row['url'] can be:
1. "img/relative.jpg"
2. "/img/absolute.jpg"
3. "//external.com/external.jpg"
-->
<img src="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>">
<a href="internalLink.html">internal link</a>
</body>
```

Since I moved all image to cdn server, so I only need to change base url for img tag only, what is the simplest way to change base domain for image only? I don't what to edit each img in whole website.

Comment: There is no such thing as a base href for images only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript like this:

```
$('img').attr('src', function(i, val) {
   return val.replace('www.mydomain.com', 'cdn.mydomain.com')
});
```

It's not the optimal way, better to do this in the server side (if you can) but it doe's the job.

Comment: But his hrefs are relative, dont contain the actual www.mydomain.com. 
He could add the missing part. But, and Im not sure about this, wouldn't this solution have a ton of 404s before the script fixes the images? I think he might be better off editing the html server side.

Comment: Yes, I tested, and got many canceled. So I cannot use this solution. Is htaccess can help in this problem?

Comment: I don't test it, but maybe you can create images handler on the server and redirect the request to the same path on your CDN server. I don't know linux so I don't know if you can do it in `htacess`.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285216/cdn-related-rewrite-image-urls-automatically-from-htaccess, I think it's gonna help you.